# HTML Class Name from Angular Array Element

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Angular array that contains JSON data. One of the elements is the name of an ionic icon. I am using ng-repeat to loop through the elements and I want to dynamically update the ionic icon name on each iteration.

```
<div class = "row" ng-repeat="item in serviceList" ng-switch   on="$index % 3">
  <div class = "col text-center" ng-switch-when="0">
      <i class = "services icon ion-laptop">{{ serviceList[$index].IconName }} </i>
  </div>

  <div class = "col text-center" ng-switch-when="0"> 
    <i class = "services icon ion-laptop">{{ serviceList[$index+1].IconName }}</i>
  </div>
```

In this example I have manually set ion-laptop, but I want to use serviceList[$index].IconName and serviceList[$index+1].IconName }} respectively to update the icon. The above code will output the icon name string, but I cannot figure out how to place that inside of the HTML class tag. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = "row" ng-repeat="item in serviceList" ng-switch   on="$index % 3">
  <div class = "col text-center" ng-switch-when="0">
      <i class = "services icon {{ serviceList[$index].IconName }}"> </i>
  </div>

  <div class = "col text-center" ng-switch-when="0"> 
    <i class = "services icon {{ serviceList[$index+1].IconName }}"></i>
  </div>
```

No big issue.. GO Ahead

Comment: `ng-class` instead of `class`